# como enviar valor do input para controle usando querystring asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho este código na View

```html
    @using (Html.BeginForm("VisualizaJogoParaExclusao", "Relatorios", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <input class="form-control input-lg " id="NumeroJogo" required onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="número"  type="text"  />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />


        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit" value="pesquisar">  Pesquisar</button>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MenuPrincipal")" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning ">
                    Retorno
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Trocar o formulário para `FormMethod.Get`
2. Adicionar o name no input
3. Pegar o resultado no controller `int idDoregistro = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["NumeroJogo"])`;

Comment: você poderia fazer a sua `action` com a seguinte assinatura: `public ActionResult NomeDaAction(int NumeroJogo)` que o input com a propriedade `name="NumeroJogo"` será implicitamente convertida para `int` não necessitando usar `Request.QueryString["NumeroJogo"]`

Answer (score 1):

Mude de `FormMethod.Post` para `FormMethod.Get` que o valor do campo será enviado como `querystring`.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo de como receber isso no controller? agradeço